# if value lies between two values then add another value to corresponding line

Tags: perl

This is a description of my problem: I have two text files (here `$variants` and `$annotation`). I want to check if the value from column 2 in `$variants` lies between the values from column 2 and 3 in `$annotation`. If this is true then the value from column 1 in `$annotation` should be added to a new column in `$variants`.

This is how my sample input files look like

`$annotation`represents a tab-delimited text file

These values can be overlapping and cannot be perfectly sorted, since I'm working with a circular genome

```
C0    C1    C2   
gene1 0     100
gene2 500   1000
gene3 980   1200
gene4 1500  5
```

`$variants` represents a tab-delimited text file

```
C0    C1
...   5 
...   10
...   100
...   540
...   990
```

The output should look like this (`$variants` with two other columns added)

```
C0    C1   C2    C3
...   5    gene1 gene4
...   10   gene1
...   100  gene1
...   540  gene2
...   990  gene2 gene3
```

This is how my script looks like for the moment

```
my %hash1=();
while(<$annotation>){
    my @column = split(/\t/);  #split on tabs
    my $keyfield = $column[1] && $column[2]; # I need to remember values from two columns   here. How do I do that?
    }   

while(<$variants>){
    my @column=split(/\t/);  # split on tabs
    my $keyfield = $column[1];
    if ($hash1{$keyfield} >= # so the value in column[1] should be between the values from   column[1] & [2] in $annotation
        push # if true then add values from column[0] in $annotation to new column in $variants
    }
```

So my biggest problems are how to remember two values in a file using hashes and how to put a value from one file to a column in another file. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Tying both files could work.

Comment: @choroba Could you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: @simbabque Could you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: @user1987607: Provide a sample input and output.

Comment: @choroba I added a sample input and output

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Never mind, the hash solution is a lot better. Forget what I said. ;)

Comment: Is the data sorted? If so, you can do this without hashes. Otherwise, you'll need a hash (or to sort the data).

Comment: How large are the two files? What is the maximal position that can occur in the data?

Comment: @choroba file are quite small (only a few KB). Maximal position is around 20000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input files are not large and the positions are not too high, you can use arrays to represent all positions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub skip_header {
    my $FH = shift;
    <$FH>;
}


open my $ANN, '<', 'annotation' or die $!;

my $max = 0;
while (<$ANN>) {
    $_ > $max and $max = $_ for (split)[1, 2];
}
seek $ANN, 0, 0; # Rewind the file back.

my $circular;
my @genes;
while (<$ANN>) {
    my ($gene, $from, $to) = split;
    if ($from <= $to) {
        $genes[$_] .= "$gene " for $from .. $to;
    } else {
        $circular = 1;
        $genes[$_] .= "$gene " for 0 .. $to, $from .. $max + 1;
    }
}

chop @genes;

open my $VAR, '<', 'variants' or die $!;
skip_header($VAR);
while (<$VAR>) {
    next if /^\s*#/;
    chomp;
    my ($str, $pos) = split;
    $pos = $#genes if $circular and $pos > $#genes;
    print "$_ ", $genes[$pos] // q(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more `#` is this script, to give some more information, cause not everything is clear to me

Comment: @user1987607: It just creates an array that represents all the positions. The index of the array corresponds to the position, the value contains all the genes at that position. It is then rather easy to search for a genes at a given position: they are directly stored at the given index.

Comment: The subroutine skip_header is made to skip only the first line I suppose?

Comment: I just tested this on my data and there are definitely some things wrong, a lot of things are classified incorrectly. I will try to figure out the reason of this and come back to you then

Comment: @user1987607: skip_header: yes. The reason: I am curious.

Comment: I detected part of the problem of misclassification. The `if $from < $to`should in my specific case be `if $from <= $to`, because sometimes my `$from` value equals my `$to`value. So that is solved. But apparently there is still a problem with the correct classification of the last value in `$variants`. There the added values are incorrect. Why ... I don't know yet.

Comment: @user1987607: What is the last value and its relevant lines in annotation?

Comment: I inserted a line to skip multiple lines starting with `#` in `$VAR`. Because in that file there are a lot of lines to exclude, not just the first. But it seems that they are still recognized since when running the script I get a warning about non-numeric values for those lines. This is the line I added in the `while $VAR` loop after chomp; `next if /^\s*#/;`

Comment: @user1987607: Are there any comments in the annotation, too?

Comment: last value is 16527 and should have three annotations, but these annotations come from lines where in `$ANN` the `$to` is smaller than `$from`. The annotation that appears is the last line from the `$ANN` but this is the wrong range. In other lines where he has to deal with smaller `$to` than `$from` values, there is no problem

Comment: No and there is in fact no header in this `$ANN` file, so I removed the `skip_header` for `$ANN`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36024/discussion-between-choroba-and-user1987607)

Answer (score 1):

No hashing needed at all. This example expects the annotations to be sorted and not overlapping, it also works only if all the values from variants should be printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $VAR, '<', 'variants' or die $!;
<$VAR>; # skip header
my ($str, $pos) = split ' ', <$VAR>;

open my $ANN, '<', 'annotation' or die $!;
<$ANN>; # skip header

while (<$ANN>) {
    my ($gene, $from, $to) = split;
    while ($from <= $pos and $pos <= $to) {
        print "$str $pos $gene\n";
        ($str, $pos) = split ' ', <$VAR> or last;
    }
}
```

Comment: @choroba. This will not work since the values from `$annotations` are overlapping and are not perfectly sorted, which is also not possible. I changed the input and output example to better fit the real situation